# Could not load file or assembly 'Noesis.Javascript, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ae36d046c7f89f85' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, dll, msvcr90.dll

I have no problem using the `Noesis.Javascript`DLL in a console application, but when I use the DLL in my web application in the development server, I get the following error:

*Could not load file or assembly 'Noesis.Javascript, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ae36d046c7f89f85' or one of its dependencies.* 
The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. 
Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B1)

First I think the problem was that in the development server, because where weren't the correct versions of the `msvc*.dll's`:

1. msvcm90.dll (9.0.30729.6161)
2. msvcp90.dll (9.0.30729.6161)
3. msvcr90.dll (9.0.30729.6161)

I installed this versions but the error still happening!

I 'm using win7 x64 and visual studio 2008 express, and the server is win2008 server R2 x64.

Can any one help me?

Comment: is the file under the "bin" directory of your web project? Have you checked if the user running the web application has access to the bin folder?

Comment: Have you checked the discussion just before the one that you created: [http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/discussions/441518](http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/discussions/441518)?

Comment: Have you tried setting in the _Build_ section of your project's properties, the _Platform target_ value to `x86` instead of `Any CPU`?

Comment: Found the solution, copy the libraries to be placed into %system32% directory instead of the "bin" directory of the application.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, mine was resolved by:

1. Download and unzip Javascript.NET from http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/
2. Copy 3 dlls (msvcp100.dll, msvcr100.dll and Noesis.Javascript.dll) into /bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this answer will help someone as none of the previous answers solved this issue for me.

Ensure that the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package is installed on the server. It can be downloaded from this link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=26999